# PHP Warning: json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding, utf-8

I know it's been asked a lot of times and ....

Yes, I searched on Google, on StackOverflow and so on, but I did not solved my problem.

I use this script taken from the internet:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql.example.com","example_example","password","example_exa");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Frasi";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

To get results and put them into an Array (mutable). The problem is that when I insert accented characters such as "à è ì ò ù" I get a "null" string, while the one without accented characters in correctly shown.

```
[{"Frasi":null},{"Frasi":"Senza accento, funziona!"}]
```

In PhpMyAdmin I set everything on UTF-8 and then to utf8mb4_unicode_ci ... but did not work.
I tried "SET NAMES 'utf-8'" but nothing.
I tried htmlentities( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE); ... and nothing

My hosting uses:

cpsrvd 11.42.1.20
Database client version: libmysql - 5.0.96
PHP extension: mysql

Server: mysql.netsons.com via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.36-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: duxnzsje@srv-hp16.netsons.net
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Any ideas, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Had a few similar problems printing json objects and please be aware that what you're passing to json MUST BE UTF-8 encoded. Therefore, please try: `echo json_encode(utf8_encode($resultArray));`.. Sometimes using UTF-8 with the database is not enough

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply .... If I do like you suggested It change from "[{"Frasi":null},{"Frasi":"Senza accento, funziona!"}]" to simply "null" :-\

Comment: can you please try this and paste the result here?: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($resultArray); echo "</pre>";` in this way we can see the structure of the array. Perhaps there is something wrong there :)

Comment: Hi Again!.. Yes, your string gives the correct results: [{"Frase":"Frase Senza Accenti"},{"Frase":null},{"Frase":"Without accented characters"},{"Frase":null}]
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Frase] => Frase Senza Accenti
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Frase] => Fràsè còn àccentì
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Frase] => Without accented characters
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Frase] => With accented characters: àà èè ìì òò ùù

éé
        )

)

Comment: Ok, now try this for each of your rows (before pushing them into the array): `echo mb_detect_encoding($row) . "<br />";`. Does everything echo "UTF-8"?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry for editing.... I see ASCII but I set everything to UTF-8 into my database!!

Comment: Oh, wait a second.. isn't $row an object? if so, try looping through the object and checking if the values are correctly encoded.. something like that: `foreach ($row as $k => $val) { echo "{$val} encoding is " . mb_detect_encoding($val) . " <br />"; }`. It should tell you what's the encoding of each element of the stdobject. If so, please tell us if all the encodings are recognized as "UTF-8" :)

Comment: Oh okay, then I'll try an answer down there, it's quite long to write here :P

Comment: :-) Thank you. You're really kind. I made a mistake inserting your code before. I will wait here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we actually saw above, the solution should be something like this:

```
<?php

            // Create connection
            $con=mysqli_connect("mysql.example.com","example_example","password","example_exa");

            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Frasi";

            // Check if there are results
            if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
            {
                // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
                // to hold the data
                $resultArray = array();
                $tempArray = array();

                // Loop through each row in the result set
                while($row = $result->fetch_object())
                {
                    // Add each row into our results array
                    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                        $tempArray[$key] = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($value), 'UTF-8', $value);
                    }
                    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
                    $tempArray = array();
                }

                // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
                echo json_encode($resultArray);
            }

            // Close connections
            mysqli_close($result);
            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

The trick seems to be there:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    $tempArray[$key] = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($value), 'UTF-8', $value);
}
```

In fact, since your values are probably not UTF-8 encoded, you can easily encode them correctly using the comfort iconv function (italian documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.iconv.php).

From the example above, we are just getting the current encoding of the string and we're converting it to utf-8 regardless its current encoding.

Hope it helps!

Also, forgot to say that: utf8_encode was NOT working because utf8_encode expects the input string to be ISO-8859-1 encoded, while the above strings are ASCII.

[image: utf8_encode]

Moreover, you should also set, in PHP, the mysqli charset manually, perhaps all the problems you're having are related to this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

---

Edit: right after connecting (after $con), try this:

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));
}
```

And, right after that, also write this:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Also, if you're echoing something, please be SURE that your HTML page as the charset defined as utf-8. In your `<head>` area, insert this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Thanks! ... but still does not works! Now I get: [{"Frase":"Frase Senza Accenti"},{"Frase":"Fr"},{"Frase":"Without accented characters"},{"Frase":"With accented characters: "}] ... it's not NULL anymore ... but It stops before an accented character! :-/

Comment: what does "print_r($tempArray);" echo? (parse it before: `array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
                    $tempArray = array();`)

Comment: Array ( [Frase] => Frase Senza Accenti ) Array ( [Frase] => Fr ) Array ( [Frase] => Without accented characters ) Array ( [Frase] => With accented characters: )

Comment: edited above: please try why I've written down there and tell me if something different happens :)

Comment: Current character set: Array ( [Frase] => Frase Senza Accenti ) Array ( [Frase] => FrÃ sÃ¨ cÃ²n Ã ccentÃ¬ ) Array ( [Frase] => Without accented characters ) Array ( [Frase] => With accented characters: Ã Ã  Ã¨Ã¨ Ã¬Ã¬ Ã²Ã² Ã¹Ã¹ Ã©Ã© ) [{"Frase":"Frase Senza Accenti"},{"Frase":"Fr\u00e0s\u00e8 c\u00f2n \u00e0ccent\u00ec"},{"Frase":"Without accented characters"},{"Frase":"With accented characters: \u00e0\u00e0 \u00e8\u00e8 \u00ec\u00ec \u00f2\u00f2 \u00f9\u00f9\r\n\r\n\u00e9\u00e9"}] ... you are getting closer, :-) I'd never been able to manage this !!!

Comment: Wait a second.. the last array is actually correct: [{"Frase":"Frase Senza Accenti"},{"Frase":"Fr\u00e0s\u00e8 c\u00f2n \u00e0ccent\u00ec"},{"Frase":"Without accented characters"},{"Frase":"With accented characters: \u00e0\u00e0 \u00e8\u00e8 \u00ec\u00ec \u00f2\u00f2 \u00f9\u00f9\r\n\r\n\u00e9\u00e9"}] This is your object CORRECTLY encoded and printed in JSON ;)

Comment: EDIT: Current character set: Array ( [Frase] => Frase Senza Accenti ) Array ( [Frase] => Fràsè còn àccentì ) Array ( [Frase] => Without accented characters ) Array ( [Frase] => With accented characters: àà èè ìì òò ùù éé ) [{"Frase":"Frase Senza Accenti"},{"Frase":"Fr\u00e0s\u00e8 c\u00f2n \u00e0ccent\u00ec"},{"Frase":"Without accented characters"},{"Frase":"With accented characters: \u00e0\u00e0 \u00e8\u00e8 \u00ec\u00ec \u00f2\u00f2 \u00f9\u00f9\r\n\r\n\u00e9\u00e9"}] Now the " print_r($tempArray);" is giving the right response!!

Comment: There you are, the above problem was still the internal encoding, while the last printing is actually your json string ;)

Comment: Thank you very very much! :-) Now I only have to test into my Xcode "experiment" .... you've been so kind! :)

Comment: you're welcome! :) If you want to learn more about encoding (which is quite important), please take a fast reading of this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html . It is quite clear and it mostly cover the basics of the encoding and why you should use utf-8 almost everywhere :)

Comment: I'll do! :-) I had to remove that "<meta charset="utf-8">" to let my "app" populate the array ... (I had just luck, I did not wanted to bother anymore!) so if you are experiencing empty arrays ... in a similar case, try to remove that line! Thanks again!

Comment: <meta charset="utf8"> is HTML, not PHP. It has nothing to do with PHP and if you put that line on your PHP code.. Well, of course it's not supposed to work, I'm surprised that it still went on, it should've popped you a "syntax error" ;D.

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the party. This is not supposed to be a complete answer, but it's an important info about the iconv() function of the approved answer: I had the same problem of the OP and I always got FALSE from iconv() function when my string contained at least 1 UTF-8 char, because there's an issue within a lib used by the iconv() function, as written [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63450).

So, for me the solution was to very close to the accepted one, but using the mb_convert_encoding() function instead.